# Simple convex problem, reference needed

Tags: general-topology, euclidean-geometry, convex-geometry

I am writing a paper, where I need to apply a quite simple convexity argument. But it's lengthy, and in order to save space in the paper, I would like to just cite a reference. The claim is as follows:

> Let $A\in\mathbb R^n$ be convex such that $\overline B_\varepsilon(0)\subset A$. If $x_0\in\mathbb R^n$ such that $\operatorname{span}\{x_0\}\subset\overline A$, then $\operatorname{span}\{x_0\}+ B_\varepsilon(0)\subset A$.

Here,

- $\overline A$ denotes the closure of $A$
- $\overline B_\varepsilon(0)$ denotes the closure of the $\varepsilon$-ball around zero
- $\operatorname{span}\{x_0\} = \{tx_0 : t\in\mathbb R\}$.

Sketch of proof: Let $x\in\operatorname{span}\{x_0\}$ and connect every point from $\overline B_\varepsilon(0)$ with $x_\delta$, where $x_\delta\in A$ is close to $x$. The union of all these lines is in $A$ since $A$ is convex. Also, the closer $x_\delta$ is to $x$, the more of the segment $[0,x]$ is contained in this union. Letting $\delta\to 0$, it follows that $[0,x)\subset A$. So, $\operatorname{span}\{x_0\}\subset A$. Now, we can even connect every point in $\operatorname{span}\{x_0\}$ with every point in $\overline B_\varepsilon(0)$. The union of all these lines is in $A$ and should contain $B_\varepsilon(x)$ for every $x\in\operatorname{span}\{x_0\}$.

Comment: What does $\mathrm{span}\{x_0\}$ mean?

Comment: @RobArthan $\operatorname{span}\{x\} = \{tx : t\in\mathbb R\}$. Edited for convenience.

Comment: Thanks, I guessed that was what you meant, but was surprised because I had misread the statement and thought you had  $A$ compact as well as convex. Sorry, I can't help with a reference.

Comment: If you want to publish the paper in some journal, then I think the proof can be omitted as it's quite easy and intuitive.

Comment: @WhatsUp My coauthor did not understand it immediately and you know that referees can be very bitchy about such stuff. The reasoning should not be too long but also not too short. A reference would wipe away all my worries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A two-sentence proof:

For any $y \in B_{\varepsilon}(0)\backslash\{0\}$ and any $t \in \Bbb R$, choose $z \in A$ such that $|z - \frac {\varepsilon + |y|}{\varepsilon - |y|}tx_0| < |y|$. We then have $$\left|\frac{\varepsilon + |y|}{2|y|}(y + tx_0 - \frac{\varepsilon - |y|}{\varepsilon + |y|}z)\right| \leq \frac{\varepsilon + |y|}{2|y|}\cdot (|y| + |tx_0 - \frac{\varepsilon - |y|}{\varepsilon + |y|}z|) < \varepsilon$$ and hence $$y + tx_0 = \frac{2|y|}{\varepsilon + |y|}\cdot \left(\frac{\varepsilon + |y|}{2|y|}(y + tx_0 - \frac{\varepsilon - |y|}{\varepsilon + |y|}z)\right) + \frac{\varepsilon - |y|}{\varepsilon + |y|} \cdot z\in A.$$

---

It's now up to the referee to check that everything is correct.

Comment: Ah, that's for the second part. Thank you! If you had a one or two-liner for the first part, too, I'd be happy.

Comment: @amsmath I updated the answer to a two-sentence proof.

Comment: Wow, this is sick! Thank you so much! My proof would have been half a page. I don't understand the geometrical intuition or construction behind this, but I could follow the argumentation.

Comment: If you would like to be acknowledged in the paper, I'd be happy to do so. Just send me your data in PM.

Comment: Oh thank you for that ^_^ I'm glad that it helped, and I don't feel strongly about ownership of the proof. You can simply use it as you wish, or, if you like, state that the proof is given by user WhatsUp on stackexchange.

Comment: I'll consider this. Although it sounds a little bit weird, right? ;-) I'll ask my coauthors.

Comment: Barf! The referee would likely put the paper to one side for another day faced with all that tedious algebra to justify something that is essentially geometric. I would strongly recommend amsmath either to use the proof sketch in the question, or just say something like "the following lemma is easily proved".